# How to use v-if from global function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is my vue component code

```
<div v-if="$can('employee-create')" class="card-tools">
              <router-link to="/admin/addphonebook" class="btn btn-success">
                Add New
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              </router-link>
            </div>
```

This is resources/assets/js/mixins/Permissions.vue file

```
export default {
methods: {
    $can(permissionName) {
        let route = window.routes.permission;
        axios.get(route+`/${permissionName}`)
            .then((resounse)=> {
                return true;
            })
            .catch((error)=> {
                return false;
            });
    },
},
```

};

This is resources/assets/js/app.js to import the mixin

```
import Permissions from './mixins/Permissions';

Vue.mixin(Permissions);
```

The $can function returning true but the 'Add New' button is not showing

v-if don't get the return true value

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You get a promise from axios. And it's undefined when rendering. Store the permission check's boolean value in data(), and defend your backend. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@Csaba Gergely* solved your problem. When you get data from server $can method return true once for a second or less, but after call $can steel returning false. You can create a variable called it `success` and store the axios call result.

It must be something like this

```
<div v-if="success" class="card-tools">
              <router-link to="/admin/addphonebook" class="btn btn-success">
                Add New
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              </router-link>
            </div>

export default {
data(){
 return {
    success:false
  }
},
methods: {
    $can(permissionName) {
        let route = window.routes.permission;
        axios.get(route+`/${permissionName}`)
            .then((resounse)=> {
                this.success = true;
                //return true;

            })
            .catch((error)=> {
                this.success = false;
               //return false;
            });
    },
},
```

*P.S. Bocsi @Csaba Gergely, ha elhappoltam eloled a kerdest :(*